# Google's protocol buffers in Golang

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

Does Go support Google's protocol buffers

(**Protocol buffers are a language-neutral, platform-neutral extensible mechanism for serializing structured data.**)

Answer (score 3):

Simple search with Google (irony?) reveals [protobuf](https://github.com/golang/protobuf)